# pecl install mongodb on mac, fatal error: 'Security/Security.h' file not found

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, pecl

I used `pecl` to install MongoDB extension on mac, but it fails

I get the following error:

> ERROR: 'make' failed
>
> /private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-rand-common-crypto.c:25:10: fatal error: 'Security/Security.h' file not found
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-rand-common-crypto.lo] Error 1
>
> ERROR: `make' failed

What is wrong?

Comment: @W.Ambrozic thanks

Answer (score 0):

fixed,
the real problem is Security/Security.h can't be found in macOS 10.14.3, and there is another similar problem to CoreFoundation/CFBase.h
it can be fixed by following steps:

```
cd mongodb-1.5.3/include
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ Security
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ CoreFoundation
brew install pcre
make
```

done

Attention:"ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ Security" may be failed because there is a "security" directory in your "include" directory.(MAC OS X's default setting is case-insensitive)
My solution is "mv security _security".